# redirecting old dynamic pages to new one with friendly url's (Codeigniter)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, routes

i spend many hours to solve my problem, but it won't work
pls, help me, i'm working with it since the end of december (proove here: http://forum.php.pl/index.php?showtopic=225498&hl=)

i wanna to redirect users from my old page, based on pure php, without CI,
to my new page based on CI

i've made yet rules to redirect static pages from old page, but i've problems with redirect dynamic pages based on ID and other parameters.

my .htaccess file looks like that right now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/billboard_lokalizacja\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=lokalizacje&id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tablice_reklamowe/billboard_id/ [R=302,L]
```

when I enter url:

```
my-server/billboard_lokalizacja.php?site=lokalizacje&id=13
```

it redirects me to:

```
my-server/tablice_reklamowe/billboard_id/?site=lokalizacje&id=13
```

but i wanna to redirect from this urls:

```
my-server/billboard_lokalizacja.php?site=lokalizacje&id={NUMBER}
my-server/billboard_lokalizacja.php?site=lokalizacje&id={NUMBER}&variable=value
my-server/billboard_lokalizacja.php?site=lokalizacje&id={NUMBER}&variable=value&variable2=value2
```

to this one:

```
my-server/tablice_reklamowe/billboard_id/{NUMBER}
```

pls. Give me some advice, its hard to understand for me right now, but I need to run new page as soon as it is possible.

i thought i could made some redirect method in my controller and use rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/billboard_lokalizacja\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^site=lokalizacje&id [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tablice_reklamowe/redirect/ [R=302,L]
```

but my Tablice_Reklamowe_Controller / redirect($string) method wont get access to $string.

$string is empty, 
current_url() returns only `http://my-server/tablice_reklamowe/redirect.`

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, I know you're looking for a `.htaccess` solution, but I just did this in a very simple, SEO friendly way (and I don't want to mess with the voodoo of the `.htaccess` file):

```
<?php

class Old_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect(str_replace('old_controller', 'new_controller', "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"), 'location', 301);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Source: [StackOverflow Question + Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994722/codeigniter-rename-controller-301-redirect-old-urls)